# Recursion using ng-include and ng-repeat doesn't work after first level

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-include

I want to recurse an object to populate a table.

For this, I am using `ng-include` and `ng-repeat` to go thru the object and create a new `<tr>` for each new element but it fails after the first level.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lsbect13/

Comment: Your `<table>` structure doesn't look valid. Try replacing all the `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>`, etc with `<div>`s and you will see it renders recursively.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating new arrays rather than new objects. Try this instead:

```
  "nodes": [{
  "name": "Level 1",
  "att1": "att1-level1",
  "att2": "att2-level1"},
    {"name": "Level 2",
    "att1": "att1-level2",
    "att2": "att2-level2"},
    {
      "name": "Level 3A",
      "att1": "att1-level3a",
      "att2": "att2-level3a"}
    , {
      "name": "Level 3B",
      "att1": "att1-level3b",
      "att2": "att2-level3b"
    }]
```

[it works!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4pOT.png)

Comment: Hi Joey,  one of the challenges is to create new object and find a way to recurse it. I can't change the way the object looks because it comes that way from the server

Comment: @HugoNakamura Can you edit it before it gets to the ng-repeat?

Comment: Probably, yeah... That's not my plans to make a flatten function but I guess  that will be the solution. I was trying to have some  solution similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/V9a2Z/

Comment: my only other suggestion would be messing around with a <script> tag.  Try updating the array ng-repeat is looping through with each pass. Not sure you can do that though